# SQL: Use a calculated fields from the SELECT in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL query that does some ranking, like this:

```
SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY XXX ORDER BY yyy,zzz,oooo) as ranking, * 
FROM SomeTable
WHERE ranking = 1 --> this is not possible
```

I want to use that ranking in a WHERE condition at the end.

Now I nest this query in another query and do filtering on the ranking there, but is there no easier or faster way to filter on such values from the SELECT statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a CTE (Common Table Expression) - sort of an "inline" view just for the next statement:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY XXX ORDER BY yyy,zzz,oooo) as ranking, 
        * 
    FROM SomeTable
) 
SELECT * 
FROM MyCTE
WHERE ranking = 1 --> this is now possible!
```

Comment: Thanks. The next time before I ask a question about a SQL query I will ask myself the question ´Will a CTE be a solution´?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the former posting, i forgot : windowing functions can only be used in select or order by clauses.
You'll have to use a sub query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY XXX ORDER BY yyy,zzz,oooo) as ranking, * 
  FROM SomeTable
) t
WHERE ranking = 1
```

OR A CTE.

Comment: This works, but that is what I already did (nesting) and I kinda asked for other ways to do this. Thats why I accepted marc_s his answer, the's the only one who gave me an other solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
select RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) as ranking, *  
from PostTypes
) A
where A.ranking = 1
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/59515

Comment: This works, but that is what I already did (nesting) and I kinda asked for other ways to do this.